# Changing the window title when focussing the window doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, focus

I'm (ab)using the document title as some kind of a notification area. If the tab/window in question doesn't have focus at the time I want to notify the user of something, I change the window title to include some notification.

When the window/tab comes back into focus, I want to remove the notification, i.e. reset the title to standard. This resetting, however, sometimes doesn't work in Chrome.

When I come from a *different window*, the title gets updated correctly, but when I come from a *different tab within the same window*, it doesn't.

I have found a workaround for this (I'll post it as an answer), but please share any other ideas you might have to fix this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome regarding the actual redrawing of the tab title, since the document title itself (i.e. within the DOM) is in fact updated correctly.

I suppose that changing the tab (which causes the tab to move to the foreground, hence to be redrawn) and changing the title within the resulting focus event (which also requires a redraw) cause some kind of race condition.

That's why I tried this workaround, which does in fact work:

```
window.setTimeout(function () { $(document).attr("title", newtitle); }, 200);
```

– just wait for a short time before updating the title, so the two redraw events don't conflict with each other. That's not pretty, obviously, but a 0.2 second delay shouldn't usually be a problem.

Comment: `$(document).attr('title', newtitle)`? `document.title = newtitle` is simpler.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H: I think I actually use `document.title = newtitle` (I actually think I tried both, to rule out the possibility of a jQuery problem). Either way, who cares? Both work, both are clear, both do the same.

Answer (score 1):

although tiftik said this bug is fixed, it still happend at my Chrome (Version 21).

The solution balpha offered works for me too - but be aware not to set the document title to the new title on Focus and than wait 200ms to set it again - This won't work! (probably because Chrome thinks it is the same title, so it won't update)

Just wait 200ms and set it - works fine!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: this bug is currently fixed.

Comment: Chrome 28: it is not.

Comment: Chrome 29.0.1547.57 m - Not fixed

Comment: we *think* this bug is fixed as we had a workaround in place for it that we no longer need @balpha